# play video landscape Iphone sdk 3.2 4.0 with standard api

Tags: ios, video, ios4, landscape, playback

how to play video landscape with standard api?

video play only portrait !!!

change the app orientation landscape is not useful, because video start portrait forever.

i have a portrait app with a button, when pressed video must play landscape.

```
yourmoviecontrollername  setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

is not allowed by Apple

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the regular videoplayercontroller doesnt do landscape by itself...i would suggest using MPMoviePlayerViewController available in 3.2, you set it up and use view controllers presentMoviePlayerController method in order to display, should work fine for you. here is a ref [MPViewcontroller](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/reference/reference.html)